# Separar valores de un array JSON con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, array

Necesito ayuda para obtener los valores que deseo.

Tengo hecha la siguiente consulta, que reúne campos de distintas tablas:

[image: Consulta]

Bien, yo en mi .php mediante la funcion **fetch_row()** obtengo cada  registro de la consulta (como pueden ver en la imagen, son 4 registros). Asumo que esta función me está devolviendo lo siguiente:

- *un **array que contiene a los 4 registros**, y **esos registros, a su vez, son arrays** que contienen cada dato que les corresponde.*

Mi código de php es el siguiente:

```
<?php

$id_alumno=$_POST['id_alumno'];

require_once 'connect.php';

$sql_taller="SELECT asig.DetalleAsignatura, 
plantaller.id_planilla_de_taller, prof.nombre_y_apellido, 
plantaller.Tcurso, plantaller.division, plantaller.comision, 
plantaller.FechaInicio, plantaller.FechaFinalizacion, 
plantaller.Bimestre, plantaller.ciclo_lectivo
FROM planilla_de_taller plantaller, profesores prof, 
asignaturas asig, alumnos_por_taller alxtaller
WHERE alxtaller.Id_Alumno='$id_alumno' AND 
plantaller.id_asignatura=asig.IdAsignarutas AND 
plantaller.Id_Profesor=prof.id_profesores AND 
alxtaller.Id_Planilla_Taller=plantaller.id_planilla_de_taller AND 
asig.TipoAsignatura='Taller' 
ORDER BY plantaller.FechaInicio DESC";

$querytaller=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_taller);

while($regtaller=$querytaller->fetch_row()){
    print json_encode($regtaller);
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

La función **json_encode()** me devuelve cada registro que se encuentra dentro del array. Aquí tienen una imagen:

[image: Registros del array]

Bien, ahora viene el problema. Yo necesito acceder individualmente a cada valor dentro de los registros. Por ejemplo, necesito solamente acceder al 1er registro e imprimir "MEP ROBOTICA". Por lo tanto, teóricamente para poder acceder al primer array, modifico la línea de **json_encode()** de la siguiente manera:

```
print json_encode($regtaller[0]);
```

Es decir, seleccioné la posición [0] del array, lo que me tendría que devolver el primer registro. Sin embargo, me devuelve la columna completa de "DetalleAsignatura" en lugar del primer registro:

[image: Modificando json_encode]

Yo en ese momento pensé: "Bueno, no importa, si pongo:"

> json_encode($regtaller[0][0])

quizás pueda acceder a "MEP ROBOTICA" igualmente. Pero no, lo que hace es tomar la primer letra de cada asignatura e imprimirla, quedando tal que así:

[image: Modificacion numero 2]

En fin, ese sería el problema. No puedo acceder a lo que yo deseo, que sería recorrer cada registro a mi gusto y tomar el dato que yo desee, sin que lo acompañen otros datos. Cualquier aporte es bienvenido. Muchas gracias de antemano.

> Actualización: array_shift()
>
> ```
> $querytaller=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_taller);
>
> $regtaller=$querytaller->fetch_row();
>
> $data=json_encode($regtaller);
>     $imp = json_decode($data, true);
>     $imp2 = array_shift($imp[0]);
>     print_r($imp2);
> ```
>
> Actualización 2: var_dump($regtaller)
>
> ```
> array(4) { 
>  [0]=> array(10) { 
>   [0]=> string(12) "MEP ROBOTICA" [1]=> string(3) "141" [2]=> string(13) 
>   "Gabriela Gill" [3]=> string(1) "6" [4]=> string(1) "1" [5]=> string(1) 
>   "A" [6]=> string(10) "2019-06-19" [7]=> string(10) "2019-08-09" [8]=> 
>   string(16) "1er Cuatrimestre" [9]=> string(4) "2019" 
>    } 
>   [1]=> array(10) { 
>    [0]=> string(19) "MEP PROGRAMACION II" [1]=> string(3) "138" [2]=> 
>    string(14) "Walter Hidalgo" [3]=> string(1) "6" [4]=> string(1) "1" [5]=> 
>    string(1) "A" [6]=> string(10) "2019-04-01" [7]=> string(10) "2019-08-09" 
>    [8]=> string(16) "1er Cuatrimestre" [9]=> string(4) "2019" 
>   } 
>  [2]=> array(10) { 
>   [0]=> string(10) "MEP WEB II" [1]=> string(2) "80" [2]=> string(14) 
>    "Walter Hidalgo" [3]=> string(1) "5" [4]=> string(1) "1" [5]=> string(1) 
>    "B" [6]=> string(10) "2018-08-13" [7]=> string(10) "2018-12-04" [8]=> 
>    string(16) "2do Cuatrimestre" [9]=> string(4) "2018" 
>   } 
>  [3]=> array(10) { 
>   [0]=> string(18) "MEP PROGRAMACION I" [1]=> string(2) "36" [2]=> 
>   string(19) "Alejandro Arriagada" [3]=> string(1) "5" [4]=> string(1) "1" 
>   [5]=> string(1) "B" [6]=> string(10) "2018-04-02" [7]=> string(10) "2018- 
>   08-08" [8]=> string(16) "1er Cuatrimestre" [9]=> string(4) "2018" 
>  }     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en este caso te devuelve todos los valores porque estás imprimiendo desde un ciclo While, para tu inconveniente podrías usar la función [array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-shift.php) fuera del ciclo o con un for ir imprimiendo dentro del while, prueba lo siguiente:

**Actualización**

```
while($row = $querytaller->fetch_row() ) {
      $regtaller[] = $row;
}

$data = json_encode($regtaller);
        $imp = json_decode($data,true);
        $imp2 = array_shift($imp[0]); //con esto accedes a la posición del array a imprimir $imp[1],$imp[2],etc...
        print($imp2);//puedes usar print o print_r
```

Parece que muestra el error debido a que no generas el array con la edición del código, por lo que le sugiero dejar el while para crear el array y luego acceder al mismo con array_shift como lo dejé arriba. Para depurar el código le sugiero también usar var_dump() para ir imprimiendo las variables o ver si $regtaller viene como array, al igual que $imp, $imp2, etc.

Comment: Al parecer no me lo permite. Me da este error: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\tallerxampp\legajotest.php on line 21.

Parece ser que la variable $imp está almacenando un string en lugar de un array y por eso array_shift no me lo permite.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código donde implementa el array_shift?

Comment: Ahí edité la publicación y agregué el código donde se encuentra el array_shift()

Comment: Actualicé el código de respuesta

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Ahora si puedo seleccionar la asignatura que deseo. Otra pregunta: cómo hago en caso de que quiera cambiar de columna? Es decir, una vez que ya imprimí la asignatura ahora deseo imprimir la columna "id_plantilla_de_taller" que le corresponde.

Comment: Ya que si hago lo que comentaste en el código sobre: $imp[1], $imp[2], $imp[3] ... llega un momento en el que no hay más asignaturas, y ahí es cuando deseo pasar a la columna de "id_plantilla_de_taller" e imprimir datos de ahí

Comment: En ese caso ya no sería necesario array_shift, dicha función accede solo al primer elemento del array, por lo que puedes usar directamente **$data[0,1,2,3,etc] ya que se le asignó el json_encode($regtaller)**, por último, si te sirvió la solución puedes marcar la respuesta, saludos!